# saving an image, chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, download

I'm trying to save an image with chrome extension when the user right click it and select the option (with Context Menu).
However the image is in the below format and the src is invalid when I am trying to download it:

```
<img id="CourseChart" src="/ChartImg.axd?i=charts_0/chart_0_0.png&amp;g=7cff9e1ede0e484bb53addfaf32423a5" alt="" usemap="#CourseChartImageMap" style="height:450px;width:800px;border-width:0px;">
```

Is there any way to do that with javascript (with chrome extension)?

Thank you.

- If it's possible, I want to download it without the user clicking it - as soon as the page is up.

Comment: Use [chrome.downloads](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/downloads) API in your background script listener for chrome.contextMenus.onClicked.

Comment: @wOxxOm, Thanks for the quick reply, I'm kind of new to it, can you explain it more extensively?

Comment: I don't know what needs to be explained. See the documentation I've linked. If you need examples, see the [demo extensions](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/samples#search:downloads) or find tutorials using site search like google.com.

Comment: Did not find anything useful, perhaps I'm missing something.

Comment: Not sure how I can help then other than writing the entire code for you, which I won't do. Let's hope someone else will.